# Xcode: Library is not build for x86_64 valid architecture

Tags: xcode, x86-64, 32-bit, i386

Please help me with issue I break my neck with..

I work with `Xcode 4.5.*` and I try to build a library with Build Settings:
Architectures: *32-bit Intel*
Valid Architectures: *i386 & x86_64*

But after checking the library details with lipo command I see that the actual library is built only for i386

Now I know this **works** in `Xcode <=4.3` - the library is built for both architectures

Thanks
Roman

Comment: Set Architectures to i386 & x86_64?

Comment: It creates many cast conflicts in code(long to int conflicts) (which I can't change because of some reasons) which is 32-bit only. 
I'll stress it again - this works in xcode 4.3

Comment: Post a new question to get help solving the cast conflicts.

Comment: I don't want to solve cast conflicts.. I know this works in sooner xcode. This is probably Xcode4.5 issue and there is maybe an answer for that..